# How to reduce the size of Background of TextView?

Tags: android

Is their any way to reduce the size of background of TextView. I am getting problem with background of textView when I increase the size of text or when I change the Font of Text then the background increases more than the size of Text. So I need a way to reduce or remove the background of TextView.

When I increase the size of TextView the size of Background also Increase Left side of the below image shows the result when i increase the size of Text. But i dont want to increase the size of the background right side of image shows the result that i want. please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
android:padding = "0dp"
```

Comment: @MikeLaren Thanks. Actually I enter this site usually to search for the solved questions, related to my problems and answer (sometimes)qxns related to my tags if I find within my knowledge. Still fresh in SOF. Thanks you made this a bit clear.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to remove the background of the text view, just put it transparent, try either :

```
android:background="@null"
```

or

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

or in Java code

```
myTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: @EI_Mochiq please read my question again i have post a image that will help you to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting margin to textview as negative number.
Hope that will work though I don't know is it a right way to do it or not,but it will work